# Can't connect to gitblit when run as service on windows

Tags: git, gitblit

I've installed gitblit successfully. When running gitblit.cmd everything works and I can connect from remote computers.

Though when I start it as a service, the service starts just fine, and I can visit it through localhost. But I cannot connect from remote computers any more.

For example I can execute `gitblit-1.6.2\amd64\gitblit.exe` and the server starts and I can connect remotely, but when installing gitblit as a service with amd64 I have the same issue with not being able to connect remotely.

I've tried everything that I can think of by now but I need some suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: does the service run?

Comment: have the same problem, i installed gitblit successfully, have https and http running both fine localhost and remotely using the gitblit.cmd batch. when i start the windows service, i only can connect via localhost and only http, not https and not remotely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to open a port in your Windows firewall.